# Problem setting up Sendmail's SMTP authentification - doesn't accept login

Tags: email, configuration, authentication, sendmail

I have no idea what's wrong with this, but for some reason I can't get my email program (Thunderbird) to send mail via Sendmail. There seems to be virtually no help on the subject on the web.

**Here's what's going on:**
I can receive email just fine. I can send email through PHP. But when I try to set up the SMTP in Thunderbird, I get a variety of errors. My goal is to be able to use port 25 or 465 with SSL. I found a site that explains how to set up a certificate with Sendmail to get that to work, but I haven't done that yet, so for now I'm just using port 465 with no encryption. I've got it to the point that it asks for a password, but it won't accept it. I'm using the same username/password I use to login to the server. How do I make Sendmail accept my login?

**Here's how I've got Sendmail configured (copied from the M4 config file):**
DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Name=MTA,Port=25')
DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Name=SMTPS,Port=465,Modifiers=a')

**I need to be able to:**
Send email over port 25 or 465 (SSL), but *ONLY* with my username & password.

Can anyone help????

Thanks!
Grant

--------------------
PS- I'm still kindof a beginner with Sendmail, especially its config file, so if you could explain exactly how to do whatever I need to do, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Port 465 requires SSL encryption, your client will not be able to use it without encryption. You can setup SMTP authentication on the default port 25 without encryption (but that exposes your login details).

Here is info to get you going https://devhen.wordpress.com/2006/05/01/howto-sendmail-smtp-auth/

Comment: I tried adding the lines mentioned in the link, but it still doesn't work. Here's a link to my M4 file, maybe it'll help:

http://prudlow.com/files/m4.txt

Note: I tried adding the certificates my imap server in an attempt to get SSL working, but that didn't work either. Still, 1st priority is getting authentication working; it's still either rejecting my password or timing out. :/

Comment: What errors are you seeing in your log files.